# Pulumi gives invalid aws:region error when deploying to AWS

Tags: pulumi, aws-regions

I am having a tinker with Pulumi having fallen out of love with Terraform. However, when following the gettins started guide, I'm receiving the following error when running ***pulumi up***

```
Diagnostics:
  aws:s3:Bucket (my-bucket):
    error: 1 error occurred:
        * Invalid AWS Region:
```

The pulumi.yaml file contains only this:

```
    config:
  aws:region: eu-west-1
```

Does anyone get this issue or does anyone know how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance,

Angus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this problem was specific to the `3.6` version of Pulumi AWS provider. Version `3.6.1` and newer should work fine.

Original answer: This appears to be a bug in the latest version of the AWS provider. Please rollback to version 3.5 of the `pulumi/aws` npm/py-pi/Go/NuGet package while we are working on a fix.

Comment: Version 3.5 of what? The aws cli?

Comment: AWS Pulumi provider (npm/py-pi/Go/NuGet package `pulumi-aws`)

Comment: Thanks to Mikhail!  To solve this issue I ran the following command npm i @pulumi/aws@3.5.0 and bingo!! It worked.